# Docker: data volume container is not instantiated with `docker create` command

Tags: docker, data-persistence, volumes

So, I'm trying to package my WordPress image in a way that all files except the uploads are persisted. In order to do so, I have created my Dockerfile which uses the official WordPress image as its base, and adds the files from an archive (containing all the WordPress files, themes, plugins, etc.), like so:

```
FROM wordpress

ADD archive.tar.gz /var/www/html/
```

Since I want the uploads to be persisted, I have created a separate data volume container, e.g. `test2.com-wp-data`:

```
docker create -v /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads —name test2.com-wp-data wordpress
```

Then I simply mount it via `—-volumes-from` flag:

```
docker run —name test2.com --volumes-from test2.com-wp-data -d --link test2.com-mysql:mysql myimage
```

However, when I inspect my newly created container, I cannot find `/var/www/html/wp-content/uploads`:

```
# docker inspect -f '{{.HostConfig.VolumesFrom}}' test2.com
[test2.com-wp-data]    

# docker inspect -f '{{.Volumes}}' test2.com
map[/var/www/html:/var/lib/docker/vfs/dir/4fff1d36d5aacd0b2c73977acf8fe680bda6fd891f2c4410a90f6c2dca4aaedf]
```

I can see that both `/var/www/html` and `/var/www/html/wp-content/uploads` are set up as volumes in my `test2.com-wp-data` data container:

```
# docker inspect -f '{{.Config.Volumes}}' test2.com-wp-data
map[/var/www/html:map[] /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads:map[]]
```

I know that the `wordpress` image by default creates a `/var/www/html` volume, for which I don't really mind, but does that mean that anything that is below that folder is ignored if mounted separately? Will I need to build my own WordPress image in order to have `/var/www/html/wp-content/uploads` set as a volume in my WordPress container?

Thank you very much for your time!

EDIT: I've tested a different setup with a folder that has nothing to do with `/var/www/html`, and the result is the same: `—-volumes-from` is ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Version 1.4 + of docker should be what you need to get this working.  Older versions of docker don't seem to play nicely with data-only containers instantiated with "create" rather than "run".

Answer (score 0):

Well, after some further testing I've realised that despite what the documentation indicates, `docker create` alone is not enough to get a working data volume working. I've only managed to get working data volumes by instantiating them with the `docker run` command, as follows:

```
docker run —-name data -v /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads mysql true
```

This way the container exits immediately, but if I use it to attach the data volume to another container it works as expected.

If anyone knows any specific reason behind this behaviour, I'd be glad to learn more, especially since the documentation seems to be misleading.

Thanks!

EDIT: It turns out I was using Docker 1.3.x, which hadn't implemented this feature yet, hence why the documentation was misleading for me!